# Thinkpad E14 Gen 4 not booting installer

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, 22.04, thinkpad

I have recently bought a ThinkPad E14 Gen 4 with an Intel core-i7 1260P, and am trying to dual boot Ubuntu 22.04 LTS alongside Windows.

My laptop came with Windows 11 Pro preinstalled and I have not messed with that or my UEFI settings. I flashed the image (from Canonical's website) to a USB drive using Rufus, and attempted booting to it. However, when I select the USB drive in the boot menu, nothing happens - once I exit the boot menu, the laptop just boots back to Windows.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** Go into your BIOS/UEFI using the F1 key. Then go to *Security* > *Secure Boot* > toggle *Allow Microsoft 3rd party UEFI CA* to be *on*. Save and exit (F10), and then use F12 to boot to the Ubuntu install media.

---

I found the source of the problem. It was Secure Boot, though that initially confused me because [Ubuntu is supposed to support secure boot](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/).

Well, I found this strange option in the BIOS/UEFI and decided to investigate: `Allow Microsoft 3rd party UEFI CA`. Turns out that Lenovo had published a document advising about this change, mandated by Microsoft: https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/Enable_Secure_Boot_for_Linux_Secured-core_PCs.pdf

Enabling that setting allowed me to boot to the Ubuntu installer.

I did this on a ThinkPad E14 Gen 4 running Windows 11 Pro with BitLocker enabled. Consequently, when I booted back to Windows, I was asked for a BitLocker key. I was able to follow [instructions from Microsoft's website (given on the screen when asked for the key)](https://support.microsoft.com/windows/where-to-look-for-your-bitlocker-recovery-key-fd2b3501-a4b9-61e9-f5e6-2a545ad77b3e), but you might want to consider retrieving/storing said key before you change UEFI settings.

Comment: This solution worked for me when installing Fedora 38 Workstation on a ThinkPad P14s gen 3. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it didn't flash correctly, try **Ventoy** instead of Rufus,
its easier

Comment: Didn't help. Ultimately seems like Microsoft was messing around with secure boot. See my solution.